# SQL server CASE error appear

Tags: sql-server

```
CASE tbl_Customer C WHEN C.gender = 1 THEN 'Male' END
```

I got a problem which could not find any answer from interner the error is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: It seems incorrect but can you show the whole query?

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
select CASE WHEN C.gender = 1 
            THEN 'Male' 
            ELSE 'Female'
       END as gender
from tbl_Customer C
```